# Does PHP interpreter compiles to bytecode every command during the reading?

Tags: php, php-internals

Could you please clarify, PHP interpreter  compiles  to bytecode every command and then executes or it first reads all commands and then compiles  and executes them?

Comment: The second is the case, but on a per file base.

Comment: Bytecode CANNOT be compiled with intuitive methodology (as in variables declared and understood etc). The only way that code can be compiled is in the way it is written - then it is attempted to be executed using the inputs and processes as it is written, from start to finish in the way the logic flow is written.

Comment: If you're using an opcode cache, then this is only done once per file (unless you actually change that file and force a refresh to the opcode cache) - See http://www.slideshare.net/jpauli/yoopee-cache-op-cache-internals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that PHP needs to parse the whole file in order to execute it cleanly, without syntactic errors in it.

An opcode cache (if installed as a Zend extension), can cache the opcodes by replacing the original function to compile a file and execute it only when necessary.

Start exploring from http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_compile.h line 675 if you would like to know the whole story.

The reason it's all or nothing it's because if a script has syntactic errors and it's already been halfway executed, then it's impossible to undo any damage it may have caused (it's not possible to undo a network communication for instance).

The reason it's on a per-file basis though (and not all or nothing) is for optimisations, since includes and requires can be conditional, not to mention autoloading.